# 8 months won’t sleep more than 2 hours

Tags: infant, sleep

I read many post on the site relating to “8 months” and tried but it didn’t work. Our 8 months ( 2 weeks less than 9 months) has been very cranky.

He wakes up on every little sound or if his bouncer isn’t rocking. In night it has been painful for us. He wake up every 2 hours, flip and stand up. It won’t go back to sleep and won’t stop crying when we try to make him sleep. It’s has been very traumatic for me as I lost job because my wife can’t handle him and he cries all day and I can’t find time to job hunt. He has totally stopped me thinking of even having more kids.

We tried to feed him before sleep so he stays full, that sometimes work to max of 3 hours but he won’t anything too expect for sweet and just spoon of it. Anything we buy or cook for him which is salty he won’t eat.

Some might say he is too big for bouncy which is correct but he won’t go to sleep without rocking unless literally too tired and his pacifier which he suckle all the time. He does has constipation.

Comment: This is not an answer, because its based on one person's experience alone (mine). When my son woke up frequently during the night, it was because he was gassy. Here're all the steps we took to reduce gas during night time:

1. simethicone drops before bed time (for example mylicon)
2. a lot of physical activity during the wake window before bedtime.
3. include massage and cycling legs in night time routine (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBBPughgJM0)
4. Put baby down sleepy but awake (nothing to do with gas, but helps baby learn to go back to sleep on his own if he wakes up)

Comment: Has he recently started solids? A food allergy could be the cause of an upset tummy (&constipation). Try cutting out dairy and see if you have a noticeable improvement. A visit to a physician to check for other issues may also help.

Comment: @eipi yes he started solids at the of writting and it has been 2 months, one noticeable thing was his 4 front teeth came out together, we thought it might be that but the crying is like a habit now, after every 2 hours, sometimes he will be crying till 1am-2am

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it should be pointed out: A 8 month old should eat neither sweet nor salty, but just the plain thing (like potatoe, carrots, whatever...)

Comment: We have a 9mo and the first thing that came to mind when I read your question was teething.  Even if the teeth are out, they could still be sensitive.  Maybe try some oragel to numb the gums before you put him down and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken him to the pediatrician?  It's not uncommon for a child to wake up throughout the night but at this age it should be getting better.  If the diaper is dry and clean and the baby is full and there isn't anything that you see that may be bothering him then it seems to be a habit.  When this happened to us we used the cry it out method.  We knew there wasn't anything wrong so we let our kids cry and self soothe and soon after that the issue was resolved.

Comment: While I understand the theory of crying it out, your post has one conclusion that seems the crux of it:  clean, fed and “there isn't anything that you see” -> I learned the hard way that some issues can’t be easily seen, yet need addressing, not letting the baby cry.